# Pass Parameter to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using jQuery Tools (http://jquerytools.org/) and cannot get the below function to accept a passed parameter.  I'm not proficient in javascript or jquery and cannot find a solution anywhere that will make this work for the below code.  Thank you for any help!

Current setup:

```
<a href='javascript:popup();'>Text Link That Calls Below Function</a>



<script>
function popup() {
if ($("#facebox").hasClass("init")) {
    $("#facebox").overlay().load();
}
else {
    $("#facebox").addClass("init");
    $("#facebox").overlay({

     // custom top position
     top: 260,

     mask: { color: '#838383',
         loadSpeed: 200,
         opacity: 0.5
     },  
     closeOnClick: true,
     load: true
    });
}
}
</script>
```

I would like it to do something like this...

```
<a href='javascript:popup(apples);'>Text Link That Calls Below Function</a>



<script>
function popup(choosebox) {
if ($("#choosebox").hasClass("init")) {
    $("#choosebox").overlay().load();
}
else {
    $("#choosebox").addClass("init");
    $("#choosebox").overlay({

     // custom top position
     top: 260,

     mask: { color: '#838383',
         loadSpeed: 200,
         opacity: 0.5
     },  
     closeOnClick: true,
     load: true
    });
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `javascript:` urls. Don't use `onclick` either - register the events using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a string as an arguement, unless you have a variable named apple defined above (`var apples;` ). Try changing it like below,

```
<a href='javascript:popup("apples");'>Text Link That Calls Below Function</a>
```

Note the quotes surrounding the `popup("apples")`

Since you are using jQuery, you can do it nicely like below,

**HTML:**

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class="aLink" >Text Link That Calls Below Function</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.aLink').click(function () {
        popup("apples");
    });
});
```

Also I think you may need to change your selector like below,

```
function popup(choosebox) {
    var $choosebox = $("#" + choosebox);

    if ($choosebox.hasClass("init")) {
        $choosebox.overlay().load();
    }
    else {
        $choosebox.addClass("init");
        $choosebox.overlay({
    //..rest of your code
```

Comment: Should you use `href='javascript:void(0)'` instead to avoid triggering a hashchange?

Comment: @tedski Agree and Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The unobtrusive javascript approach is generally considered better and the JQuery way.

```
$('a.someclass').click(function() { popup('orange'); });
```

Providing you give your `<a>` element has a class of "someclass" in this example.

This keeps your js seperate from your html. That code could go in document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a click event for a class on that anchor, then determine which "box" is related to that link by reading a data- attribute. This will give you a generic, reusable block of jQuery code that can be called by any anchor tag matching this pattern.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="popup" data-choosebox="apples">Text Link That Calls Below Function</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.popup').on('click', function(e){

        var $_target = $('#' + $(this).data("choosebox"));

        if ($_target.hasClass("init"){
            $_target.overlay().load();
        } else {
            $_target.overlay().load({

                top: 260,
                mask: { color: '#838383',
                        loadSpeed: 200,
                        opacity: 0.5 },
                closeOnClick: true,
                load: true
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
​
```